# Connection lost whenever I lock the computer

Tags: windows-xp, networking

I recently formatted my PC and installed Windows XP SP3.

Now whenever I lock my computer (Windows + L) or (Ctrl + Alt + Del) it loses the LAN connection.

Are there any registry hacks or something else that might be causing this? It didn't behave this way prior to the formatting.

Answer (score 4):

From a quick search,

> The sp3 install might have reset your
>   power management settings so it goes
>   into standby at 15 minutes (this is
>   default on a lot of HPs). A quick
>   google search shows that some people
>   are having problems with sp3 and power
>   management. If it goes into standby it
>   will drop the network connection to
>   save power. Set it to never go into
>   standby or hibernate.

Try changing the power management settings.

Answer (score -2):

In services.msc check for service ###string. if it is there disable it.